# How to use ZXingScannerFragment in PageRenderer

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, zxing.net

Since the `ZXing.Net.Mobile` has a problem on forms after 2.2.0 updates, I need to separate the `ZXing` into different platform. But the android version cannot work in `PageRenderer`.

Here is the info of my project:

Xamarin: **10.10**

Android version: **API 23**

Project: **Xamarin PCL Forms**

ZXing version: **2.1.47**

App.Android - AndroidManifest:

```
 <manifest ...../>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
          <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <application ....
```

App.Android - MainActivity.cs :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
           base.OnCreate(bundle);
           MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);

}
```

App.Android - QRCodePageRenderer :

```
class QRCodePageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
        private ZXingScannerFragment ScanFragment;
        ZXingSurfaceView ZxingScanningView;
        private Android.Views.View ZxingOverlay;
        FrameLayout frame;
        public bool ContinuousScanning { get; set; }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var activity = this.Context as Activity;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            frame = (FrameLayout)layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.zxingscannerfragmentlayout, null);
            ZxingScanningView = new ZXingSurfaceView(activity);
            ScanningOptions = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
            ScanningOptions.PossibleFormats = Constants.QRCODE_SCAN_FORMAT;


            try
            {
                var scanner = new ZXingSurfaceView(activity, ScanningOptions);
                var layoutParams = getChildLayoutParams();
                frame.AddView(scanner, layoutParams);
                ZxingOverlay = new ZxingOverlayView(activity);
                frame.AddView(ZxingOverlay, layoutParams);
                this.AddView(frame);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Create Surface View Failed: " + ex);
            }

            ScanFragment = new ZXingScannerFragment();
            ScanFragment.TopText = "ABC";
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("StartNew scan .....");

                    ScanFragment.StartScanning(result => {

                        if (!ContinuousScanning)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
                            Console.WriteLine("Stopping scan...");

                            ScanFragment.PauseAnalysis();

                        }
                    }, this.ScanningOptions);

                });

            }
 }
```

**Update 2017-05-15**

Screenshot of the QRCodeReader
[image: Screenshot of the QRCodeReader. It has empty view]

Comment: What do you mean with "But the android version cannot work in PageRenderer" ? what error are you receiving?

Comment: There is no error, but i will attach the screenshot of the mobile later. I hope that there is an errors, but no after checking logs.

Comment: @apineda There is no errors or any exceptions. The view returned empty.

Comment: Before looking into your implementation I wanna ask you what's the problem you found with Zxing and Forms using ZXingScannerPage? I am using this library with a Xamarin.Forms project 2.3.4.224, Zxing 2.2.9, Android Version  24 and I haven't seen any problem.

Comment: @apineda The problem is that the ZXing of iOS version has bugs https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/544 which cannot work perfectly. That makes me to build QRCode Scanner on each platform

Comment: @apineda I still cannot add the view, is a bug of the plugin or something wrong on my code?